# 404 error in react project I published with caprover

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, caprover

When we publish a react project on caprover, it gives 404 error when refreshing the page. my caprover nginx settings are default. My dockerfile is like this

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build

ENV NODE_ENV production

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npx", "serve", "build" ]
```

Comment: What is the default coprover nginx config?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/yunus-acar/ab0e6ff517af8274eca54fe1c57fb812 this is the nginx configuration from the default when the project is created

Comment: What does the caprover log say? Are you able to login to the caprover dashboard?